# Slick carousel not adapting to responsive images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slick.js

I want to use the Slick  carousel with some images that will resize depending on the width of the screen, however whilst the images are responsive, the carousel always fills the whole page.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick-theme.css"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="slide">
            <div><img src="images/slide1.jpg"/></div>
            <div><img src="images/slide2.jpg"/></div>
            <div><img src="images/slide3.jpg"/></div>
        </div>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="slick/slick.min.js"></script>

    </body>        
</html>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.slide').slick({
      dots: true,
  });

});
```

CSS:

```
.slide{ 

}

img{
    max-width: 50%;
    height: auto;
}
```

I have tried playing with the .slide class but I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: "the carousel always fills the whole page" - please explain in detail as a carousel will fill the full viewport width no matter the breakpoint, unless restricted to a container or there is additional css/js we cannot see. Also, please place this in a JSFiddle or CodePen

Comment: @Ben I have uploaded a screenshot so you can see and added a border to the .slide container to make it clearer. https://imgur.com/a/rHVlo I want the .slide container to always fit the height and width of the image.

Answer (score 1):

you have to force slick to resize :

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  $('.js-slider').slick('resize');
});

$(window).on('orientationchange', function() {
  $('.js-slider').slick('resize');
});
```

or maybe this is shorter :

```
$(window).on('resize orientationchange', function() {
  $('.js-slider').slick('resize');
});
```